# Can anyone give me an example of Bhurich Gayatri Mantra?

Tags: vedas, mantras, gayatri-mantra

In vedas , The poetic metre Gayatri has 24 syllables .

As far as I know,

In vedas , When the poetic metre has less than the required number of syllables, it's called as 'Nichrit' and when more than the required number of syllables, it's called as 'bhurich' or 'bhurik'.

Since the Gayatri Mantra of Savitr Dev has 23 syllables in it , it's called Nichrit Gayatri .

So , is there any example of a mantra written in Gayatri Chhandas (Poetic Metre) which is designated as 'Bhurich' or 'Bhurik'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examples can be Mantras of Rigveda [4.10.2,3,4](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/rig-veda-english-translation/d/doc832349.html) which are in Bhurik Gayatri Chhanda (25 letters):

> अधा ह्यग्ने क्रतोर्भद्रस्य दक्षस्य साधोः । रथीॠतस्य बृहतो बभूथ ॥ 2
>
> एभिर्नो अर्कैर्भवा नो अर्वाङ्स्वर्ण ज्योतिः । अग्ने विश्वेभिः सुमना अनीकैः ॥ 3
>
> आभिष्टे अद्य गीर्भिर्गृणन्तोऽग्ने दाशेम । प्र ते दिवो न स्तनयन्ति शुष्माः ॥ 4  
> *(Rigveda 4.10)*